# read wrapped text with read.table()

Tags: r, word-wrap, read.table

I have data with 25 variables that have been output from another program. For most of the cases (rows), the other program wrapped the text for the 24th and 25th variable to the line below, like this:

```
v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21 v22 v23
v24 v25
```

In other cases, only the 25th variable is wrapped below, like this:

```
v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21 v22 v23
v25
```

Is there a way to read the tab-delimited file into R so that the last two variables are grabbed from every other row and added to the 24th and 25th column as needed, so that the result would be an object with 25 unique variables?

I think it might have something to do with using the skip option in read.table().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. I'm using `scan` with the text argument for demo purposes, but you would supply the path to your file.

```
x <- c("v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21 v22 v23",
"v24 v25", 
"v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21 v22 v23",
"v24 v25")

values <- scan(text=x, what='')
do.call(rbind, split(values, rep(1:(length(values) %/% 25), each=25)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try: (Using `x` from @Matthew Plourde)

```
library(stringr)
indx <- str_count(str_trim(x), " ")==1 #str_trim(x) in case there are leading, trailing spaces, remove it
read.table(text=paste(x[!indx], x[indx]),sep="")
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
#1 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21
#2 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21
#  V22 V23 V24 V25
#1 v22 v23 v24 v25
#2 v22 v23 v24 v25
```

In case, the spaces between the variables are not constant, for example

```
 x1 <- c("v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21 v22 v23",
 "v24     v25", 
 "v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21 v22 v23",
 "v24  v25")


  x1 <- gsub("(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])\\s+(?=[A-Za-z0-9])", " ", x1, perl=TRUE)
  indx <- str_count(str_trim(x1), " ")==1 
  read.table(text=paste(x1[!indx], x1[indx]),sep="")
```